# How do I perform field validation within the Angular typescript and not in the form?

Tags: html, angular

Due to specific requirements, I need to validate the presence of my delivery.address field within the typescript code, so I am calling a function, addressIsValid(), to do this as shown in the code below.

```
<div class="col col-md-6 col-lg-12">
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="address" id="address" 
    [(ngModel)]="delivery.address" #address="ngModel">
    <ng-container *ngIf="delivery.method=='Delivery'">
        <div *ngIf="!addressIsValid()" class="primary-color">
            <!-- <div *ngIf="address.invalid && (address.dirty 
                || address.touched)" class="primary-color"> -->
            Address is required
            <!-- </div> -->
        </div>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

Typescript function:

```
public addressIsValid() {
    return !this.delivery.address == undefined 
        && !this.delivery.address == null;
  }
```

The problem is after valid value is entered into the field, the error message: "Address is required." does not go away. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in your `addressIsValid` function.

Take this 2 objects for example:

```js
const o = { name: 'john' };
const o2 = { name: undefined };
```

`!o.name` --> `false`;
`!o2.name` --> `true`;

Neither of the above fulfills the condition `== undefined` or `== null`.

Thus, you will always get a falsy value.

You could modify your function like this:

```js
public addressIsValid() {
    return this.delivery.address !== undefined 
        && this.delivery.address !== null;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably wanted to check this:

```
public addressIsValid() {
    return !!this.delivery.address;
  }
```

[example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9xkbqu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

If that is not the case you need to debug what this.delivery actually contains after your method call.

```
console.log(this.delivery)
```

And tell us what that contains.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest reading about [Angular Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#reactive-form-validation). You can easily define validation rules in TypeScript and drive the display of error messages in your view.

```js
  this.heroForm = new FormGroup({
    'name': new FormControl(this.hero.name, [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.minLength(4),
      forbiddenNameValidator(/bob/i) // <-- Here's how you pass in the custom validator.
    ]),
    'alterEgo': new FormControl(this.hero.alterEgo),
    'power': new FormControl(this.hero.power, Validators.required)
  });
```

```html
  <div *ngIf="name.errors.required">
    Name is required.
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="name.errors.minlength">
    Name must be at least 4 characters long.
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="name.errors.forbiddenName">
    Name cannot be Bob.
  </div>
```

Also take a look at the `FormBuilder` [service](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#step-2-injecting-the-formbuilder-service), which will help condense the form creating syntax.